# launching (auto launch) bfgminer on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi

I drill down to the folder where bfgminer.exe lives on my Raspberry Pi with Raspbian OS and issue this command:

screen -S Mining .bfgminer –o http://mint.bitminter.com:3333 –u username.myname –p 123

I get a command not found message. I have tried everything I can think of to get the syntax correct. Where am I going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to install screen if it's not installed by default:
    sudo apt-get install screen

Comment: this does not look like an answer to question

Comment: TarangP, Are you saying it doesn't fix the issue or that it's not verbose enough?  I found this post looking to solve this exact problem myself, so I came back to share what solved it for me: **installing screen**. Could there be other answers? Sure. But no one has attempted to answer.